# TextView on top of Custom View

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

How do I display the TextView below the CustomView?  Right now TextView is on top of CustomView text.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/gamelayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<com.sample.CustomView
android:id="@+id/customview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="top"
/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/displayMetrics"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5sp"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:text="METRICS"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to move its declaration in the layout so that the `TextView` goes first.

Comment: Now the TextView disappeared when switching around.

Comment: @David: Its below your custom view, which I guess is not transparent.